# Get fixed position based on underlying div if still exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I created a rough idea of the filter I'm creating offline.

Basically the filter or "update row" section shows red, blue or green if available. Can be any combination of results(ie. just blue and green) I have a div that's positioned at the top at all times. So when viewing the blue section it is over that row(fixed to top).

If I select the filter the positioning is lost as you can imagine as sometimes rows will not be present from above or the underlying row may not exist anymore. My question is. How can I get the row name underneath at click then use that to scroll to once everything else is complete. Of course if it's not present then just go to top of table_listing.

[image: I'm lookin]

```
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            jQuery('#table_listing').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow'); // put our list of links into it
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#table_listing").offset().top
                }, 1000);
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Do you want to check your "#table_listing" to see how many blocks you have and what colors they are?

Comment: No I'm looking to check what div row the fixed div is currently overlapping when a selection is made. This way, when I output the table_listing again I can have the page scroll back to this area of interest. When an "update row" button is clicked the row will update with new information. Does that make sense?

Comment: How does this overlapping happens anyway? by clicking the div. If this is true, then you can do this. You can define a variable and change it when you choose one of the divs. This way, you can keep track of the latest clicked divs. For instance, your variable can be 1 if first div is overlapping, 2 when the second is overlapping, and 3 for the last one.

Comment: The overlap happens as you scroll. So the div is fixed to the top of the page and stays at the top as you scroll.

Comment: So you want to know which div (red or blue or green) is overlapping by the fixed div on top?

Comment: Right so which div the fixed div is overlapping so I can return there if it exists after the filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101242/discussion-between-hfw-and-zero-point).

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example [HERE](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/adEwaa).

So the idea is to use `$(document).scrollTop()` to find how much the page is scrolled. Then compare it with the height of the divs to find the one we are on. Then we store it in a variable in a dynamic manner. When user clicks filter button, we know where we have been before, so we can scroll back to that element. Check out the console to see the result. Since `scroll()` event is only bind to user manual scrolling, it will not be affected by animating of scroll, as you want to have.